# Why scanf in bison grammatical rule not working?

Tags: scanf, bison

I have this gramatical rule in my .y file

```
...
    listaIdentificadores  :listaIdentificadores ',' ID {leer($3);}
                          |ID {leer($1);}
    ;
...
```

and this is definition of leer()

```
void leer(char* identificador) {
    int valor;
    scanf("%d",&valor);
    cargarTS(identificador, valor);
}
```

but when scanf() should be executed it does not ask for the keyboard input and it simply continues with the execution of the following code line.

Comment: I am not familar with **Bison**, but are you leaving any newlines (`\n` or pressing `Enter`) or any other characters in the input stream *before* the `scanf()` from other `scanf()`s, reads, et cetera?

Comment: You are going to have to provide more code than that. Where is the lexer getting its input from? If it is also coming from standard input, it's very hard to see how that can "work" (although it's also not clear to me what you are trying to do).

Comment: I'm using 'flex', getting the characters from the standard input. maybe later I can upload all the code

Comment: "getting the characters from the standard input". So when you call `scanf`, do you expect that to read from the file that you're piping into stdin? So does that mean that after the `ID` token there will be a number in the source and you want `scanf` to read that number? If that's the case, you should just add an integer token to your grammar rule instead of `scanf`. If you're trying to read user input independently from reading the source code, you can't read both from stdin.

Comment: So why don't you just let flex read the numeric tokens from the input stream?

Comment: I try to build an interpreter. Then I need to read () function as scanf ()

Comment: @Cosmonauta First of all, you can't read input from stdin as the same type as you're reading the source from stdin? How should that work? Do you want the user to enter the source code, followed by some terminator and then the input? If so, that won't work because your actions are going to be evaluated while the source is being read, not after. Secondly, trying to run the program while parsing it, isn't going to work anyway. As soon as you try to implement `if`s or loops that way, you're going run into trouble. You'll want to make your parser generate an AST or bytecode and then ...

Comment: ... evaluate that as a separate step.